# How can you pass an ifstream to thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, ifstream

I'm trying to implement multi-threading in my program. I'm trying to make my directory searcher run in a thread, and join for the rest of the function.

The file thread function searches my directory and finds each file, and I'm trying to use this in my file reader section within my `main()` function.

How should I pass an `ifstream` path to a thread? After a lot of googling, I'm not any closer to finding an answer due to it being so specific.

```
void file_thread(std::ifstream& file){
    //open csv file for reading
    std::string path = "path/to/csv";
    for (const auto & f : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)){
        std::ifstream file(f.path());
    }
}

int main(){
    std::ifstream file;
        
    std::thread test(file_thread, file);
        
    //if csv is successfully open
    if(file.is_open()) 
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What happens when you have the proper parameter list in `file_thread`?

Comment: sorry my mistake, after fixing this I still get an error message regarding using the 'file' name. I'm just not sure if im extracting the correct param to pass over the ifstream. **Added my current code to original post**

Comment: `std::ifstream file(f.path());` creates a new file variable that hides the function argument.

Comment: `std::thread test(file_thread, std::ref(file));` would get the code to compile. It's not clear though why the thread would want to take `ifstream` object as a parameter. It's perfectly capable of creating its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you actually want this, although its not at all clear why you are using a separate thread

```
void file_thread(std::ifstream& file){
    //open csv file for reading
    std::string path = "path/to/csv";
    file.open(path);
}
```

If thats the path, why iterate over the directory

This code still wont help if you call it in a separate thread as main will not wait. Why not just call normally?

```
std::thread test(file_thread, file);
// the line below will run before file_thread finishes
// thats the whole point of threads

if(file.is_open()) 
{
    ...
}
```

just do

```
file_thread(file);
    
//if csv is successfully open
if(file.is_open()) 
{
    ...
}
```